# Redirecting when trying to log in with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I am building an ASP.Net MVC5 application that uses forms authentication. It is set to redirect to ~/Account/Login when the user tries to view a page but they are not authenticated. However, my login also accepts a parameter, company. The problem is, if a user is not authenticated and tries to go to page ~/Account/Login/CompanyA the program redirects to ~/Account/Login/

Is there any way to avoid this initial redirect? Once you are on the Account/Login page you can enter a company name and go to that url, but the very first time you try to access the site it redirects you.

Any suggestions?

I can post any code if needed.

Here are my actions:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login(String company)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(String company, LoginModel model)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(company))
    {
        company = WebLogin.GetDefaultCompany();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the Login actions?

Comment: The Login actions are decorated with AllowAnonymous and HttpGet - HttpPost

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the code, and see if it is actually hitting the action? Is there a value on the company parameter, or is it null? Run Fiddler to see what responses you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the Request.QueryString object to try and find any string passed in and parse that to redirect to the proper Login screen. A Bit of a workaround, bit it does the trick.